# Maven- Remove a Jar while building from lib folder

Tags: java, maven, jar

i have added a jar like below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

but in the war file creation , i don't want this in the `lib` folder. I know that `scope` tag with `provided` value would do that, but here the `scope` is already defined as `system`. Could you please guide me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Change scope `system` to `provided`

Comment: Think about putting the jar into a Maven repository to avoid system scope. If you do not want to run a Nexus/Artifactory, you can also define directories as Maven repository.

Comment: we have nexus repository, its like a web link , where you can navigate. Any Idea how to search a jar file through that ? so that i can add it as Nexus? since its a very big repo, navigate and find is very difficult actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `maven-war-plugin` add the following to exclude the jar file from packaging.

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <packagingExcludes>
                WEB-INF/lib/com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
            </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

Comment: `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <!-- <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}\WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->      
     <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
     <finalName>web</finalName>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>` this is from my pom.xml . since i have `warSourceDirectory` could you pls tell me where we should add `packagingExcludes`

Comment: According to my knowledge the jar's are copied into the META_INF/lib folder. So you need to specify the `<packagingExcludes>` within the `<configuration>` tag in your `maven-war-plugin` as I have described. So it will skip adding the mentioned jar to the `lib` folder.